# How to redirect my php validation form to another page

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation, contacts

I'm really struggling here! I have a contact form which I will include that uses the jquery plugin, and uses php as a backup. This form is not all the way customized yet, but I am having trouble for a couple of days now. When I use MAMP and click submit the validation works perfectly! in both php and jquery. Then redirects me to google(eventually some other website).
When I upload it to my companies site under a TEST folder. to test it I get the validation and everything working perfectly. When I submit after fixing errors in jquery it pushes to google like it is supposed to. When I take away the jquery to test the php, the validation works then when I hit submit it just stays right there on the same index.php page! I have been pulling my hair out trying so many different contact validation forms and this one seems to be working the best. I am a graphic designer with enough web experience to get me in trouble with PHP!:) Can anybody help with some advice?

Here is my index.php

```
<?php include('header_contact.php') ?>


<?php include('testval.php');?>




<div id="section1">

CONTACT FORM

<div id="contact-form">




<!--<form id="contactform" name="contactform" action="<!--?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" >-->
<form id="contactform" name="contactform" action="index.php" method="post" >



    <!--?php
    if($sent === true) {
        echo "<h2 class='success'>Thanks, your message has been sent successfully</h2>";
    } elseif($hasError === true) {
        echo '<ul class="errorlist">';
        foreach($errorArray as $key => $val) {
            echo "<li>" . ucfirst($key) . " field error - $val</li>";
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    ?>
    -->

    <input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" placeholder="NAME" value="<?php echo (isset($Name) ? $Name : ""); ?>"><span class='text_error'><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>

    <input name="Company" type="text" id="Company" placeholder="COMPANY" value=''>

    <input name="Phone" type="tel" id="Phone" placeholder="PHONE" value='<?php echo htmlentities($Phone);?>'>
    <span class='text_error'><?php echo $phoneErr;?></span>

    <input name="Email" type="Email" placeholder="EMAIL" value="<?php echo (isset($Email) ? $Email : ""); ?>">
    <span class='text_error'><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>

    <input name="webdesign" type="checkbox" value="Yes" /><label>Web Design: </label><br />

    <input name="webhosting" type="checkbox" value="Yes" /><label>Web Hosting: </label><br />

    <input name="wordpressdesign" type="checkbox" value="Wordpress Design" /><labeel>Wordpress Design: </labeel><br />

    <textarea id="Describe" class="mess" name="Describe" type="text" placeholder="DESCRIBE WHAT YOU NEED"><?php echo isset($_POST['Describe'])? $_POST['Describe'] : ''; ?></textarea>
    <span class='text_error'><?php echo $describeErr;?></span>

    <!--?php if(in_array('Describe', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><!--?php echo $error_messages['Describe']; ?></span><!--?php endif; ?>
    <span class='text_error'>
    -->

    <input class="input-upload" type="file" name="Upload File">

    <input name="Human" placeholder="5 + 3 = ?" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['Human'])? 
    $_POST['Human'] : ''; ?>">
    <span class='text_error'><?php echo $humanErr;?></span>

    <!--
    <!--?php if(in_array('Human', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><--?php echo $error_messages['Human']; ?></span><--?php endif; ?>
    -->

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">




</form>






</div><!--END CONTACT FORM-->

</div><!--END SECTION1-->    







<?php include('footer.php') ?>
```

Here is my testval.php

```
<?php

session_start();
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $phoneErr = $describeErr = $humanErr = "";
    $Name = $Email = $Phone = $Describe = $Human = "";

    $hasError = false;
    $sent = false;

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $Name            = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Name'], ENT_QUOTES));
        $Email           = trim($_POST['Email']);
        $Describe        = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Describe'], ENT_QUOTES));
        $Phone           = trim($_POST['Phone']);
        $Email           = trim($_POST['Email']);
        $webdesign       = trim($_POST['webdesign']);
        $webhosting      = trim($_POST['webhosting']);
        $wordpressdesign = trim($_POST['wordpressdesign']);
        $Human           = trim($_POST['Human']);
        $Number          = 8;

        $fieldsArray = array(
            'Name' => $Name,
            'Email' => $Email,
            'Describe' => $Describe,
            'Phone' => $Phone,
            'Human' => $Human
        );

        $errorArray = array();

        foreach($fieldsArray as $key => $val) {
            switch ($key) {
                case 'Name':
                    if(empty($val)) {
                        $hasError = true;
                        $nameErr = "Please enter your name.";
                    }
                case 'Name':
                    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", ($val))) {
                        $hasError = true;
                        $nameErr = "The value must be alphanumeric."; 
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Phone':
                    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", ($val))) {
                        $hasError = true;
                        $phoneErr = "Only numbers and white space allowed.";
                    }
                case 'Phone':
                    if(empty($val)) {
                        $hasError = true;
                        $phoneErr = "Phone is required.";
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Email':
                    if(!filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                        $hasError = true;
                        $emailErr = "Email is required.";
                    } else {
                        $Email = filter_var($Email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Describe' :
                    if (strlen($val) < 25) {
                        $hasError = true;
                        $describeErr = "Please enter at least 25 characters. This way I know more specifically what you need!";
                    }
                case 'Describe' :
                    if(empty($val)) {
                        $hasError = true;
                        $describeErr = "Message is required. This way I know what you need!";
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Human':
                    if (!preg_match("/[^\d]?8[^\d]?/", ($val))) {
                        $hasError = true;
                        $humanErr = "Not the right answer";
                    }
                case 'Human':
                    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", ($val))) {
                        $hasError = true;
                        $humanErr = "Must be a number";
                    }
                case 'Human':
                    if(empty($val)) {
                        $hasError = true;
                        $humanErr = "Are you human?";
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        //CHECK BOX WRITE UP
        if (isset($_POST['webdesign'])) {
            $checkBoxValue = "yes";
             //is checked
        } else {
            $checkBoxValue = "no";
             //is unchecked
        }

        if (isset($_POST['webhosting'])) {
        $checkBoxValue = "yes";
            //is checked
         } else {
            $checkBoxValue = "no";
            //is unchecked
        }

        if (isset($_POST['wordpressdesign'])) {
        $checkBoxValue = "yes";
            //is checked
        } else {
            $checkBoxValue = "no";
            //is unchecked
        }

        //Validation Success!
        //Do form processing like email, database etc here
        if($hasError !== true) {
            $priority = $_POST['priority'];
            $type = $_POST['type'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $formcontent=" From: $Name \n Company: $Company \n Email: $Email \n Phone: $Phone \n Describe: $Describe \n Web Design: $webdesign \n Web Hosting: $webhosting \n Wordpress Design: $wordpressdesign ";
            $recipient = "creative@griffard.com";
            $subject = "Contact form test with Jquery and PHP";
            $mailheader = "From: $Email \r\n";
            mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);
            header("Location:http://www.google.com");
            exit();       
        }
    }

?><!--END PHP-->
```

I took out the jquery for now to test the php to get it working, but when it is in the index.php page it is right below

here is the code for that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#contactform").validate({
        rules: {
            Name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
            Email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            Describe: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 25
            },
            Phone: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                minlength: 7,
                maxlength: 15
            },
            Human: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                maxlength: 1,
                range: [8,8]
            }
        },
        messages: {
            Name: {
                required: "Please enter your name",
                minlength: "Your name seems a bit short doesn't it?"
            },
            Email: {
                required: "We need your email address to contact you",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },
            Describe: {
                required: "Please enter your message",
                minlength: "Please enter at least 25 characters. This way I know more specifically what you need!"
            },
            Phone: {
                required: "Please enter your phone number",
                number: "Phone has to be numbers",
                minlength: "Your phone number should be longer",
                maxlength: "Number must be less!"
            },
            Human: {
                required: "Are you human?",
                number: "has to be a number",
                maxlength: "That's to long!",
                range: "Please enter the correct number"
            }
        },
        errorElement: "div", //TAKE CONTROL OF ERROR MESSAGE IN CSS

        //IF I CHOOSE TO ADD CSS AND WRAP ERROR WITH BOX

        wrapper: "div", //WRAPPER AROUND THE ERROR MESSAGE
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
            error.addClass('message'); //ADD A CLASS TO THE WRAPPER
            /*
            error.css('position', 'absolute');
            error.css('left', offset.left + element.outerWidth());
            error.css('top', offset.top);
            */
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Test elementary. Do you receive the mail? Put your redirect in the first position with you `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) ` and see if the redirect is working.

Comment: Yes it redirects doing that. putting it back at the end sends me an email with the content just doesn't redirect page at all.

Comment: Seems like your redirect is interrupted by some error that is send to your browser. Set your error reporting on at the beginning of your php script. `error_reporting(-1);` and see if php spits out something to the browser.

Comment: Yes there is an error.

Comment: Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/rainmakerimports/public_html/TEST/header_contact.php:37) in /home/rainmakerimports/public_html/TEST/testval.php on line 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are parsing HTML in your `header_contact.php`. You cannot parse HTML content before a redirect. Try switching the included php files.

```
<?php include('testval.php');?>

<?php include('header_contact.php') ?>
```

Comment: no session anywhere else. when I plug in what you sent its the same error as above instead of line 6 its line 7now. because of moving session_start() down one

Comment: Something happens in your `header_contact.php` on line 37 that is causing this.  Can you post that?

Comment: just posted it... looks like the <body> tag is the last at line 30. and I have enters that go down to 37. they are blank

Comment: I think there is your answer. I changed my current answer in my post here. I think that should help you to put your wig back on ...  ;-)

Comment: Holy Crap!! you are the man! I have been stressing for a couple days now! That is a simple fix that I wouldn't realize would be a big problem! I want to learn PHP to get better at it! I appreciate all of your help and everyone who chimed in!

Comment: Keep practicing the art. Luke didn't become a Jedi overnight ..  You can accept this as  the answer to close the question.. and an upvote for bonus....

Comment: Will do! much appreciated!

Comment: That's OK .. A Jedi does not need points. Only knowledge ..  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8 BOM">

            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <title>Contact Form TEST</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/contact.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/validation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

    <!--MOO Script-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.0/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>





</head>


<body>
```

Answer (score -2):

try to change your `header` bit, at the very end of your `test.php` to something that looks like this:

```
header("Refresh:0; url=index.php");
```